# Electronic citation alignment in IEEE

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

```
@electronic{IntelNode,
  title = "Intel Intelligent Power Node Manager",
  url = "http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sysmgmt/sb/node_manager_white_paper.pdf",
  note = "Accessed: 2014-10-14"
}
```

When I try to cite this in IEEEtrans. The border line adjustment is not aligned.

Here is a snippet
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\usepackage{url}`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{url}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @electronic{IntelNode,
  title = "Intel Intelligent Power Node Manager",
  url = "http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sysmgmt/sb/node_manager_white_paper.pdf",
  note = "Accessed: 2014-10-14"
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
  \cite{IntelNode}
  \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
  \bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Done! Thanks. I will accept it in a 6min :-)